# Neo4j graphacademy learning sandbox window activation

Tags: neo4j, sandbox

I am new to Neo4J.  I am taking graph academy Neo4j online training courses.  The sandbox window/pane that is part of the online training course browser to perform challenge exercises is not working.  I am not sure how to activate the sandbox pane or connect the window/pane to a server so that I can execute Cypher query commands to get credit for the challenge exercises.  I am stuck.  Can someone let me know what should I do to get the sandbox window/pane in the online training courses working?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens when you click the sandbox icon? Please add a screenshot if possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have received a welcome email for the course from  Neo4j GraphAcademy (no-reply@mail.graphacademy.neo4j.com), including the sandbox's details.[image: Graph Academy welcome with sandbox]
2. Login to [Graph Academy](http://graphacademy.neo4j.com/) and start/resume the corresponding course[image: sandbox toggle]
3. Click the Sandbox (castle) toggle to bring the cypher shell up for the sandbox.[image: sandbox cypher]
4. If the sandbox toggle isn't working, disable popup/ad blockers in your internet browser and try again. Chrome and Firefox are more successful. Brave browser's shield is known to cause issues. Your browser's console logs might show errors in this case.
5. If all else fails, contact graphacademy@neo4j.com